# How can I test if Python http.server.HTTPServer is serving forever?

Tags: python, multithreading, http, python-3.x, thread-safety

I am writing this little demo code to start an HTTP server, test that it is running successfully and then exit.

```
import http.server
import urllib.request
import threading

# Start HTTP server
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(('', 8080), http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
thread.start()

# Test HTTP server and shutdown
print(urllib.request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8080/').read())
httpd.shutdown()
```

This seems to be working fine but it might be working fine due to luck. You see, I am invoking `httpd.serve_forever` in a separate thread, so that my script doesn't block at this call and it can continue with the `urllib.request.urlopen` call to test the HTTP server.

But I must ensure that I am making the `urllib.request.urlopen` call only after `httpd.serve_forever` has been invoked successfully and the server is now serving requests.

Is there any flag or any method in `http.server.HTTPServer` or `socketserver.TCPServer` that will help me to ensure that I begin testing it with `urllib.request.urlopen` only after it is ready to serve requests?

Comment: Do `urllib.request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8080/').read()` on regular intervals or simply check to see if the thread is running via `t.isAlive()`?

Comment: @Torxed `t.isAlive()` doesn't guarantee that `http.server.HTTPServer` is serving requests. It only guarantees that the thread is alive. I want to avoid calling `urllib.request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8080/').read()` on regular intervals.

Comment: Then you use `import select` and `.poll()` the socket object to check if it's alive (can read/write data). Because no, in some way or shape you need to manually check to see if's still running. A thread that handles such events should be enough usually. Normally you have your own `.recv()` function in a Thread, if that thread goes down it means that the server is effectively down, so checking the thread status is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your goal is to not get an empty / invalid answer in your urlopen, the answer is you won't.
You actually open a socket with this line:

```
http.server.HTTPServer(...)
```

so after it (with still one thread running) you **already** have an open socket listening for incoming connections (although nothing dispatching requests yet). After that we may have a race of two threads. Consider both possibilities:

1. The server thread runs serve_forever first. Well, it's the case you're aiming at.
2. The main thread connects first. Your connection will be accepted and will wait for something to dispatch it to the handler. Then the server thread runs serve_forever, attaches a dispatcher and your request still gets processed.

Comment: Do you mean that I need not worry about an empty/invalid response in the client? The client would always get a valid response since the server will wait for the dispatcher to be attached and then send a valid response?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The client will always get a valid response. You may check it yourself. Simply run the HTTPServer string in one console and connect with another one (i.e. curl http://localhost:8080/), then run service_forever with the first one.